# Prove that $E(Y_i \bar{Y}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\mu^2$

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given $Y_1, Y_2,...Y_n$ are i.i.d random variable which follows a distribution of $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, I'm trying to prove that $$E(Y_i \bar{Y}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\mu^2$$

Here's what I've tried:
$$E(Y_i \bar{Y}) = E(Y_i  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i )$$
$$ = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}E(Y_i  Y_i )$$
Since $E(Y_i^2) = Var(Y_i)+E(Y_i)^2 = \sigma^2 +\mu^2$
$$E(Y_i \bar{Y}) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}E(Y_i^2)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{n} n (\sigma^2 +\mu^2)$$
$$ = (\sigma^2 +\mu^2)$$
which does not prove it right. I am unsure of where i got this wrong. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: In your 2nd step, how did you take the $E(Y_i) $ inside the series?

Comment: I used the fact that $\bar{Y}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i $

Comment: I understand that. That was your 1st step. Ok, let me rewrite your 1st step:
$E[Y_i  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i] =E[\frac{Y_i}{n} (Y_1 +Y_2 + ... +Y_n)].$
Do you now see what you did wrong in the 2nd step by taking the $Y_i$ inside the series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the error in your argument caused by the choice of the index letter that is already used.

> $E(Y_i \bar{Y}) = E(Y_\color{red}{i}  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{\color{red}{i=1}}^{n}Y_\color{red}{i} )$

To be correct,
\begin{align} E(Y_i \bar{Y}) = E(Y_i  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{\color{blue}{j=1}}^{n}Y_\color{blue}{j} ) = E(\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n}Y_iY_j) =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} E(Y_iY_j) \end{align}

If $i \neq j$, we have $E(Y_i Y_j)=E(Y_i)E(Y_j)=\mu^2$. If $i=j$, $E(Y_i^2)=Var(Y_i) + E(Y_i)^2=\sigma^2+\mu^2$

Thus \begin{align} E(Y_i \bar{Y}) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} E(Y_iY_j)&=\frac{1}{n} \left( (n-1)\mu^2+\ \sigma^2 + \mu^2\right) \\ &=\frac{1}{n}(n\mu^2 + \sigma^2)=\mu^2 + \frac{1}{n}\sigma^2 \end{align}

Comment: Sorry, but may I know where did the $(n-1)$ term come from? Is it there to subtract the term where $i=j$? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. For fixed $i$, there is $(n-1)$ times of $j \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ such that $j \neq i$, and exactly one $j=i$ in $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$. Thus $$\sum_{j=1}^{n} E(Y_iY_j) = \sum_{j \neq i} E(Y_iY_j) + E(Y_i Y_i) = (n-1)\mu^2 + (\sigma^2 + \mu^2) $$